# on pageload (before any hover event in effect) do the same as hover-out event

Tags: jquery

Probably this is a trivial question. The script has a bit reversed logic. I need the hover-out to be applied by default on pageload so that the content of the data-gg attribute is shown by default instead of the i element's real content which in turn thus should be shown only on hover-on (and not by default on pageload). The script now shows by default the real i content before the first hover event is in effect, otherwise it works fine.

```
$('i[data-gg]').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).html($(this).data('content'));
    },
    function() {
        $(this).data('content', $(this).html())
               .text($(this).attr('data-gg'));
    }
);
```

Comment: you can trigger the `mouseleave` event on these objects

Comment: The mouseleave event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer leaves the element. As I said I need it before any event is in effect.

Comment: what? use `$('i[data-gg]').trigger('mouseleave')` to trigger the callback you just registered..

Comment: Right, right, thank you. First it didn't work because originally I used the hoverIntent plugin instead of hover.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the hover-out event to happen on page load, you can trigger it immediately after you register your callback (the hover registers the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events respectively):

```
$('i[data-gg]').hover(
  function() {
      $(this).html($(this).data('content'));
  },
  function() {
      $(this).data('content', $(this).html())
             .text($(this).attr('data-gg'));
  }
).trigger('mouseleave');
```